With Ignite 2.16.0, Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses in K8 environment
I am trying to run ignite 2.16.0 in kubernetes env with the following configuration.
Cluster-role.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ignite
  namespace: ignite
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: ignite
  namespace: ignite
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources: # Here are the resources you can access
  - pods
  - endpoints
  verbs: # That is what you can do with them
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ignite
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: ignite
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ignite
  namespace: ignite

deployment.yaml
# An example of a Kubernetes configuration for pod deployment.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # Cluster name.
  name: ignite-cluster
  namespace: ignite
spec:
  # The initial number of pods to be started by Kubernetes.
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignite
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ignite
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ignite
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60000
      containers:
        # Custom pod name.
      - name: ignite-node
        image: apacheignite/ignite:2.16.0
        #image: gridgain/community
        env:
        - name: OPTION_LIBS
          value: ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http
        - name: CONFIG_URI
          value: file:///ignite/config/node-configuration.xml
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "1"
          limits:
            memory: "2Gi"
            cpu: "2"
        ports:
        # Ports to open.
        - containerPort: 47100 # communication SPI port
          name: discovery
        - containerPort: 47500 # discovery SPI port
          name: communication
        - containerPort: 49112 # dafault JMX port
          name: jmx
        - containerPort: 10800 # thin clients/JDBC driver port
          name: thinclients
        - containerPort: 8080 # REST API
          name: rest
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /ignite/config
          name: config-vol
      volumes:
      - name: config-vol
        configMap:
          name: ignite-config

node-configuration.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ignite-config
  namespace: ignite
data:
  node-configuration.xml: |
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
       <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
          <property name="stripedPoolSize" value="16" />
          <property name="discoverySpi">
             <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                   <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                            <property name="namespace" value="ignite" />
                            <property name="serviceName" value="ignite-service" />
                   </bean>
                </property>
             </bean>
          </property>
          <property name="cacheConfiguration">
             <list>
                <bean abstract="true" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration" id="receiver-cache-template-bean">
                   <!-- when you create a template via XML configuration, you must add an asterisk to the name of the template -->
                   <property name="name" value="my-receiver-*" />
                   <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL" />
                   <!-- Other cache parameters -->
                </bean>
             </list>
          </property>
       </bean>
    </beans>

Service.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # The name must be equal to KubernetesConnectionConfiguration.serviceName
  name: ignite-service
  # The name must be equal to KubernetesConnectionConfiguration.namespace
  namespace: ignite
  labels:
    app: ignite
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: rest
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: thinclients
      port: 10800
      targetPort: 10800
    - name: discovery
      protocol: TCP
      port: 47500
      targetPort: 47500
    - name: communication
      protocol: TCP
      port: 47100
      targetPort: 47100
    - name: jmx
      protocol: TCP
      port: 49112
      targetPort: 49112
  # Optional - remove 'sessionAffinity' property if the cluster
  # and applications are deployed within Kubernetes
  #  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  selector:
    # Must be equal to the label set for pods.
    app: ignite
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

After starting the containers, following errors are noticed in the logs.
[21:11:40,371][SEVERE][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder (retrying every 2000ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries) [maxTimeout=0]
class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:81)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.registeredAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2057)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.resolvedAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1992)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1283)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1120)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:472)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2206)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:277)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:1076)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1774)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1161)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1725)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1647)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1089)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:983)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:889)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:808)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:678)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:647)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:325)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:365)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.kubernetes.connection.KubernetesServiceAddressResolver.getServiceAddresses(KubernetesServiceAddressResolver.java:123)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:76)
    ... 20 more

Tried all most of the suggestions on stackoverflow still same issue. If I change the image from apache to gridgain, every thing is working fine but not with image from Apache. Requirement is to use apache only.
Any help here is appreciated. Thank You.

Update on the above: After changing the image to apacheignite/ignite:2.16.0-jdk11 issues got resolved.
